# Loop in HTML Select "option" tag using JavaScript not giving result

Tags: javascript, html, ajaxform

I am trying to loop in HTML Select  in JavaScript. Below is my code. I want to display my COUNT value in option. I am getting some data from PHP end & it need to be display the count. Please advise if i am missing anything or is it wrong way ?

```js
var cjs=$form.find('[name="cjs"]').data("cjs");
var newHtml = 'Current<br>\
               <select class="form-control" id="priority" name="priority">\
               '+for (var i = 1; i <= cjs; i++) {+'\
               <option disabled selected value ="0" style="display:none">-CHOOSE PRIORITY-</option>\
               '+}+'\
               </select>\
 
                <button class=" upr edit btn btn-sm btn-primary"> Update </button></center></div>';

                    $('.proo'+request).html(newHtml);
                 alert("Successfully Updated");
```

Answer (score 0):

check this maybe it will helpful for you

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Date Picker</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the button to loop through a block of code five times.</p>

<select id="demo">
</select>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction(selector)
{
   var optionList="CHOOSE PRIORITY "
    var i;
    for (i=1;i<=5;i++){
      selector.options[i-1] = new Option(optionList+i);
    }
}
//usage:
myFunction(document.getElementById("demo"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am trying implement in var newHtml in existing function.  I am trying to populate data to a table column using  $('.proo'+request).html(newHtml); & thats why i am trying to get option data within  var newHtml